# Build the corpus by Wikipedia: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'

Tags: python, gensim

I copy a simple Python script by [Building a Wikipedia Text Corpus for Natural Language Processing](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/11/building-wikipedia-text-corpus-nlp.html) to build the corpus by stripping all Wikipedia markup from the articles, using gensim. This is the cose:

```
"""
Creates a corpus from Wikipedia dump file.
Inspired by:
https://github.com/panyang/Wikipedia_Word2vec/blob/master/v1/process_wiki.py
"""

import sys
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

    def make_corpus(in_f, out_f):

    """Convert Wikipedia xml dump file to text corpus"""

    output = open(out_f, 'w')
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)

    i = 0
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
            print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles')
    output.close()
    print('Processing complete!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('Usage: python make_wiki_corpus.py <wikipedia_dump_file> <processed_text_file>')
        sys.exit(1)
    in_f = sys.argv[1]
    out_f = sys.argv[2]
    make_corpus(in_f, out_f)
```

Anyway, I obtained the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

although I have installed the `gensim` package:

```
python3 -m pip install gensim
```

**EDIT**. If I try with

```
pip install -U gensim
```

I obtain the error

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 
 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (C:\Users\Standard\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

Comment: What command do you use to run your script? `python3 YOURFILE.py` ?

Comment: I'm using spider. My script is WikiCorpus.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the `gensim` module installed in your system.

```
pip install -U gensim
```

Or download it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim.

`gensim` depends on `scipy` and `numpy`. You must have them installed prior to installing `gensim`.

There is a bug in `pip 20.0.0`. Either upgrade to 20.0.1 using:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Or downgrade to 19.3.1.

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but I obtain the error that I described in my post, edited just now.

Comment: There is a bug in pip 20.0. Either update pip to 20.0.1 or downgrade to 19.x.x. Check my edit for how to upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: I used `conda install -c anaconda gensim`  and it seems that at least this problem has been solved